# Installing Zend Debugger on Wamp/Windows Vista

Tags: php, debugging, wamp, zend-debugger

I'm trying to make Zend Debugger run on my Wamp server on Windows Vista.

Here are steps, which I folowed:

1. Download **ZendDebugger-5.2.15-cygwin_nt-i386.zip** from http://downloads.zend.com/pdt/server-debugger/
2. Copy \ZendDebugger-5.2.15RC1-cygwin_nt-i386\5_2_x_nts_comp\ZendDebugger.dll to c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext\ZendDebugger.dll
3. Edit php.ini (checked using phpinfo(), that I'm editing right php.ini) like this:

   > zend_extension_ts=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext\ZendDebugger.dll
   >   zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1
   >   zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
4. Restart Apache
5. Copy \ZendDebugger-5.2.15RC1-cygwin_nt-i386\dummy.php to c:\workspace\www\dummy.php
6. According [this post](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/1026-cant-install-php-debugger-binaries#comment_1160548) install Zend Debugger plugin for PDT

Finally when I test the debugger by Run > Run Configurations > PHP Web Page > MyDebug > Test Debugger it says "Testing communication with client host/IP: 'localhost'... and then this:

A timeout occured when the debug server attempted to connect to the following client hosts/IPs - localhost.

Also there is not any note about Zend Debugger, there's nothing like this:
[image: Zend Debugger in phpinfo()]
<sub>(source: [thierryb.net](http://www.thierryb.net/pdtwiki/images/a/a9/Phpinfo_zenddbg_section_01.png))</sub>

Comment: *(reference)* [Zend Forum - Setting up Zend Debugger](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=962)

Comment: Could the problem be that I'm running on PHP 5.3 and trying to install Debugger for PHP 5.2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you checked the firewall?

Seems like you managed to install the debugger if its reported by phpInfo... so i'm guessing that you either put the wrong settings(localhost or 127.0.0.1 might make a difference in the settings dialog) or a firewall stopping the communication.

Comment: Firewall is turned off now, but I do **not** have Zend Debugger report in phpinfo().

Comment: Sorry, i think i misread the screenshot you posted:) i though you have it installed.

The problem might be incompatibility between versions(Zend Optimizer for PHP5.2 does not work with PHP 5.3 for example).

Did you looked into the server logs?(logs for the apache server i assume)

Comment: Solved! :)
I've downloaded PHP 5.2.11 and ZendDebugger.dll for 5.2.x and suddenly it works.