# Installing Zend Debugger on Wamp/Windows 7

Tags: php, zend-debugger

I got the latest XAMPP package and extracted it at `c:\tools php.exe -v` gives following output

```
C:\tools\xampp\php>php.exe -v
PHP 5.3.5 (cli) (built: Jan  6 2011 17:54:09)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Eclipse PDT, I am using, has this version

> Eclipse for PHP Developers
>   Version: Helios Service Release 2
>   Build id: 20110218-0911

Then I added ZendDebugger to eclipse from  `http://downloads.zend.com/pdt`, so it created folder `C:\tools\eclipse-php-helios-SR2-win32\plugins\org.zend.php.debug.debugger.win32.x86_5.3.18.v20100905\resources\php53` 
I modified `php.ini` { found in c:\tools\xampp\php } to setup **ZendDebugger.dll**

But no matter what I do, I am not able to debug my php web applications.
I get this error when I do "Test Debugger" from Eclipse
**A timeout occured when the debug server attempted to connect to the following client hosts/IPs: -127.0.0.1**
Then I came across this old post [Installing Zend Debugger on Wamp/Windows Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164529/installing-zend-debugger-on-wamp-windows-vista). Do I need to go back to old versions of php in order for zend debugger to work with Eclipse?

regards, Yogesh

Answer (score 0):

xdebug is working in my case - so this should not be a problem related to php5.3 and xdebug.

For this I'd check the following things:

- Is xdebug installed and enabled? (call phpinfo() to get more informations) If you can't find any informations xdebug is not installed.
- Does xdebug stop the script if you call the php-function xdebug_break(); ?
- xdebug needs a cookie to be activated. Is this cookie set by eclipse? Just try var_dump($_COOKIE)
- Do you have this behaviour also if you try another environment? For example netbeans or phpstorm?

If the function xdebug_break() works but the script does not stop at breakpoints set in the IDE - I'd check if the dll-file for xdebug is included as zend_extension or extension. Xdebug has to be included as zend_extension for it has to be started before the parser of php is started!

Here's a good link to explain every step in it's detais. It's related to the IDE Komodo - but the installation of xdebug is the same:
http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/5.0/debugphp.html

Bye
Simon